# sending php variables through a background URL link

Tags: php, html

I want to have a google map showing a users location as the background for a div.

Using my MAXMIND Geo-ip installation Im told to use `<? echo $_SERVER["GEOIP_CITY"];?>,<? echo $_SERVER["GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME"];?>` to display "San Francisco, USA".

So, I was using the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
<div id="main-body-map" style="background-image:url(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<?php echo$_SERVER["GEOIP_CITY"];?>,<? echo $_SERVER["GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME"];?>&zoom=14&size=245x252&sensor=false);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:center center;">
```

I'm not sure if i need to set each $_SERVER[""]; as a variable like $city first? If you simply type in city, country into the google maps link it shows a map properly. For example

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Seattle,USA&zoom=14&size=245x252&sensor=false

Also would this be better using an IP for accuracy? I also have access to an IP address look-up variable.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the output look like when you run your code? Does it have the city name in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

not really familiar using goolge maps api but try:

```
<?php
```

$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=".$_SERVER["GEOIP_CITY"].$_SERVER["GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME"]."&zoom=14&size=245x252&sensor=false";
 ?>

```
<div id="main-body-map" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $url; ?>);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:center center;">
```